Adjusting the \cftsecnumwidth in TOC seperately for two different section numbering styles?
I am using two different section numbering styles in the same document. First goes as,

AP1, AP1.1, AP1.1.1....

The second is just simple section numbering that goes as,

1, 1.1, 1.1.1...

I can call each numbering style by using \normalsections and \apsections commands as defined in the MWE.
When I generate the TOC, either longer AP numbers are too close to the headings or shorter normal numbers are too far away from heading names. I can't figure out how to separately define \cftsecnumwidth value for each section type.

Please advice me on how to get this done.
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openany, ngerman, ]{book}
    
\usepackage[newparttoc, noindentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\apsections}{%
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont AP}\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{{\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont 
    AP}\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{{\fontsize{9.5}{12}\selectfont  
    AP}\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}}

\newcommand{\normalsections}{%
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection} 
    {\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}}

% Customize spacings and indentations for TOC entries
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{12pt} % Space before chapters
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt}   % Space before sections
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{4pt}% Space before subsections
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{2pt} % Space before subsubsections

\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{2.5em}  % Indentation for chapters
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.5em}% Indentation for sections
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2.5em}{2.5em} % Indentation for subsections
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{6em}{2.5em} % Indentation for subsubsections

\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{4em}

\begin{document}
    
{
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
}

\mainmatter
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%Part I - APSection
{
\cleardoublepage
\part{Part APSections}

\apsections
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{Section AP1}

\section{Section AP2}
\subsection{Subsection AP2}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection AP2}
}

%Part II - NormalSection
{
\cleardoublepage
\part{Part Normal Sections}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\normalsections
\section{Normal Section 1}

\section{Normal Section 2}
\subsection{Normal Subsection 2}
\subsubsection{Normal Subsubsection 2}}
\end{document}


You can incorporate adequate indents and widths to the definitions of \apsection and \normalsections, replacing the global definition.
\cftsetindents{<level>}{<indent>}{<numwidth>}
sets the indent and numwidth of level <level>

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openany, ngerman, ]{book}

\usepackage[newparttoc, noindentafter]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\apsections}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.5em}} % added <<<<<<<<
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftsetindents{subsection}{2.5em}{3.5em}} % added <<<<<<<<
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{6em}{4em}} % added <<<<<<<<
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont AP}\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{{\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont 
            AP}\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{{\fontsize{9.5}{12}\selectfont  
            AP}\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}} 
    }

\newcommand{\normalsections}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{1.5em}} % added <<<<<<<<
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftsetindents{subsection}{1.5em}{2.0em}} % added <<<<<<<<
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{3.5em}{3em}} % added <<<<<<<<             
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection} 
    {\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}}

% Customize spacings and indentations for TOC entries
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{12pt} % Space before chapters
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt}   % Space before sections
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{4pt}% Space before subsections
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{2pt} % Space before subsubsections

\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{2.5em}  % Indentation for chapters
%%%\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.5em}% Indentation for sections
%%%\cftsetindents{subsection}{2.5em}{2.5em} % Indentation for subsections
%%%\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{6em}{2.5em} % Indentation for subsubsections


\begin{document}
    
    {
        \cleardoublepage
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \setcounter{page}{1}
        
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} 
        \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
        \tableofcontents
    }
    
    \mainmatter
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    
    %Part I - APSection
    {
        \cleardoublepage
        \part{Part APSections}
        
        \apsections
        \setcounter{section}{0}
        
        \section{Section AP1}
        
        \section{Section AP2}
        \subsection{Subsection AP2}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection AP2}
    }
    
    %Part II - NormalSection
    {
        \cleardoublepage
        \part{Part Normal Sections}
        
        \setcounter{section}{0}
        \normalsections
        \section{Normal Section 1}
        
        \section{Normal Section 2}
        \subsection{Normal Subsection 2}
        \subsubsection{Normal Subsubsection 2}}
    \end{document}


Thank you very much Simon. This works perfectly.
